# Spanish language chars are not displayed properly?

Tags: java, gwt, internationalization, gxt

I am using GWT. i implemented internationalization to support spanish language. but spanish chars are not displayed propertly. Ex: **Teléfono Buscar** is displayed as .
[image](see some junk char after Tel). i am using IE browser.

Do i need to configure any further settings? Thanks!

Comment: Make sure the data is encoded `UTF-8` throughout until it is displayed on the browser.

Comment: @adarshr, Thanks for your reply. i have already placed below line in my host page. <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: Where is the string coming from? How are you reading, etc?

Comment: Strings are coming from properties files(Resource Bundles).

Comment: More code would help us figure out where this is going wrong.

Comment: How do you edit your properties files? Do you use Eclipse?

Comment: we have properties files for each language. one for english and other for spanish. as we are using i18n, gwt will load appropriate java script based on client locale property. we are specifying locale in query string by appending as ?locale=es_AR

Comment: Yes i use eclipse to edit the properties files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this may be due to the fact that your editor isn't using `UTF-8` encoding.

If you're using Eclipse, you can configure it to use `UTF-8` for `*.properties` by going to `Window > Preferences > General > Content Types`.

Just make sure you change the `Default encoding` value to `UTF-8` as shown below.

[image]

There will be a similar setting for any text editor, including `vi`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your strings are coming from a properties file, your ResourceBundle is probably an instance of PropertyResourceBundle, which creates an empty instance of java.util.Properties and then populates the instance by loading the properties file via one of the "load" methods. PropertyResourceBundle has two constructors, one which takes an InputStream and one which takes a Reader. The constructors simply call the corresponding "load" method.

Note that the "load" method that takes an InputStream assumes the character encoding of the properties file is ISO 8859-1 (Latin1). You can solve this problem in two ways:

1. Ensure the property constructor of PropertyResourceBundle is being called, the one that takes a Reader. Construct the reader using the appropriate character encoding.
2. Use Unicode escapes (\uxxxx) to encode non-ASCII characters in the properties file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Reading values from properties file is simple for us we are not using any propertyresourcebundle. gwt itself creates interfaces for each properties file. we just call the interface and access the values from properties file.

Comment: If you don't have control over how the resource bundle is instantiated, the easy solution then is to use Unicode escapes in the properties file.

Comment: Unicode escapes make the files unreadable by humans if the only languages supported are English and other Latin-based languages such as es, fr, de, etc. Prefer unicode escapes only for Chinese, Korean, Arabic etc.

Comment: Please can you give me an example. consider the string Teléfono Buscar?

Comment: @user1016403: The Unicode value for é is 0x39 (U+0039, in the Unicode nomenclature). Replace the `é` with the characters `\u0039`. You can find other values at unicode.org. Word of warning, though: As adarshr pointed out, lots of Unicode escapes can severely hinder the readability of your properties file.