# Display Hindi language in console using Java

Tags: java, utf-8

```
StringBuffer contents=new StringBuffer();
BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/xyz/abc.txt"));
String line = null; //not declared within while loop
while (( line = input.readLine()) != null){
    contents.append(line);
}
System.out.println(contents.toString());
```

File `abc.txt` contains

```
\u0905\u092d\u0940 \u0938\u092e\u092f \u0939\u0948 \u091c\u0928\u0924\u093e \u091c\u094b \u091a\u093e\u0939\u0924\u0940 \u0939\u0948 \u092
```

I want to dispaly in Hindi language in console using Java.

if i simply print like this 
String str="\u0905\u092d\u0940 \u0938\u092e\u092f \u0939\u0948 \u091c\u0928\u0924\u093e \u091c\u094b \u091a\u093e\u0939\u0924\u0940 \u0939\u0948 \u092";

System.out.println(str);

then it works fine but when i try to read from a file it doesn't work.

help me out.

Comment: @missingfaktor: i think he just means the console he is using to run his program (he is not using any IDE). And he is probably on windows!!

Comment: Open the file in a browser and check if your encoding is correct? Perhaps the Java Console is not UTF capable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/).

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

// open the file as ASCII, read it into a string, then
String escapedStr; // = "\u0905\u092d\u0940 \u0938\u092e\u092f \u0939\u0948 ..."
// (to include such a string in a Java program you would have to double each \)

String hindiStr = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava( escapedStr );

System.out.println(hindiStr);
```

(Make sure your console is set up to display Hindi (correct fonts, etc) and the console's encoding matches your Java encoding. The Java code above is just the bare bones.)

Comment: but when  i am inserting into database it just inserted like ??? ??? ????????? it does not display hindi font i changed the charset utf-8.

Answer (score 5):

You should store the contents in the file as `UTF-8` encoded Hindi characters. For instance, in your case it would be `अभी समय है जनता जो चाहती है`. That is, instead of saving unicode escapes, directly save the raw Hindi characters. You can then simply read like normal.

You just have to make sure that the editor you use saves it using UTF-8 encoding. See [Spanish language chars are not displayed properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10814692/spanish-language-chars-are-not-displayed-properly/10815108#10815108)

Otherwise, you'll have to make the file a `.properties` file and read using `java.util.Properties` as it offers unicode unescaping support inherently.

Also read [Reading unicode character in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630609/reading-unicode-character-in-java)