# compiling code in java - hindi output required

Tags: java

when i compile the following code,  i am not getting any compile time error . where as the out put for the code is displayed as "?????".

i have tried compiling the code as `javac hinditest.java`

is there any way i can get output in the language that i have entered (hindi)

```
public class hinditest{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String tst = "पाततद";
    System.out.print(tst);
    }
    }
```

thanks in advance ..

Comment: What's the OS? should be Windows? And to get the output, you have to run the program. Compiling won't give the output

Comment: Where do you output ? To the windows console ?

Comment: How are you executing the code - from the command line or in an IDE?

Comment: you probably need to change the encoding of the console/environment. What OS/IDE are you using?

Comment: i have written the code in note pad and executing the code in linux platform

Comment: I get proper output both in Eclipse and in the command line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: How to detect (and change?) encoding of System.console?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415597/java-how-to-detect-and-change-encoding-of-system-console)

Comment: Try to open the terminal with `screen -U` and then execute your program

Comment: This might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950020/display-hindi-language-in-console-using-java

Answer (score 2):

`?` denotes that the character is not recognized. This happens when the charset used doesn't support the character. Please check whether encoding is `UTF-8`. You can open the terminal with `screen -U` and execute your code.

Comment: when i was checking the reasons for the kind of output that i got, many people have written about encoding in UTF-8 char set .. frankly speaking i do not know how to check it ..

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Encoding of the environment

Comment: As i understand, the encoding supported by the platform where the OP runs doesn't support this charset. so, the OP has to set the required encoding. Please check this [link](http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment)

Comment: OK, so you mean the system environment.

Comment: yes sir.. I think i have put a valid answer to the question. Did i?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It's my honour sir. I'm improving my skills to write better. Thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

you can try this ;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8");
    String tst = "पाततद";
    System.out.print(tst);
}
```

and if you are using eclipse than you can set as
Run Configuration -> Common -> Encoding -> Select UTF-8

Comment: @Shekhar +1 but I will recommend to use `UTF-16`, it will include all the characters that are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the stack over flow link below for encoding your output.
[Java: How to detect (and change?) encoding of System.console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415597/java-how-to-detect-and-change-encoding-of-system-console)

Answer (score 0):

```
String tst = "पाततद";
byte[] array = tst.getBytes("UTF-8");
String s = new String(array, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(s);
```

The String constructor cannot distinguish the charset that is being used and will try to convert it using the system standard which is generally something like ASCII or ISO-8859-1. This is why normal A-Za-z looks proper but then everything else begins to fail.

Byte is a type that runs from -127 to 127 thus for UTF-8 conversion consecutive bytes need to be concatenated. It's impossible for the String constructor to distinguish this off a byte array so it will handle each byte individually by default (thus why basic alphanumeric will always work as they fall into this range).

Comment: This is ridiculous. A String is a String, it has no encoding---or if you want, it has always the same encoding, defined by the JLS.

Comment: A book is a book and a plane is a plane. What's your point? And no, actually a String is not a String but rather an array of chars. If you still don't believe me rethink about refreshing your Java knowledge. Also, try putting different encoding into parentheses (e.g. ISO-8859-1) and you will see the output on the console MAGICALLY change!

Comment: Of course, because you have destroyed the original string.

Comment: BTW "a String is an array of chars"---and what is a char? How do you change the encoding of a char? Answer: *you can't* because that's not how Java works.

Comment: Please, please study this method `java.lang.StringCoding.decode(Charset cs, byte[] ba, int off, int len);`. Ziv bio.

Comment: Ziv bio ti meni 100 godina :) but your answer still doesn't make sense. You can't "fix" a string by dumping into a byte array then reading back that array into another string. At best you end up with the same string, otherwise you get mojibake.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the encoding property in command line as follows:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 hinditest
```