# How to split the input string into corresponding utf- charcters?

Tags: java, hindi

I have to split the strings of input text file (which is in hindi language) in java language. 
Is there is a way to do so ?I have tried to split it into single characters but that doesn't word. For example:

```
मुझे बहुत सारा काम करना है|
```

then output should be

```
मु  
झे  

ब  
हु  
त

सा  
रा

का  
म

क  
र  
ना

है
```

Comment: show us your work

Answer (score 0):

**This will solve your problem**

```
BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("your text file path goes here"));
            String read = null;
            while ((read = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] splited = read.split("\\s+");
                for (String part : splited) {
                    System.out.println(part);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was a problem: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
   }
```

Note:- provide your full file path to the filereader.

Answer (score 0):

All string data types processed in Java are 'Unicode' so you might get unexpected result.

You may refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950020/display-hindi-language-in-console-using-java). I think, it seems similar problem

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
 String s = new String("मुझे बहुत सारा काम करना है");

       for(int i =0 ;i<s.length();i++){
           System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
       }
```

Comment: Latin and Devanagari are different. Your code will give output like ` म ु झ े  ब ह ु त  स ा र ा  क ा म  क र न ा  ह ै | `. But the actual should be like `मु झे ब हु त सा रा का म क र ना है |` . You should use a different algorithm or regex for this.