I tried to print all the hindi character in vs code but it is showing "?" instead of characters
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Java1
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 2309; i <= 2362; i++)
            System.out.println(i + ":" + Character.toString(i));
    }
}

what changes do i need to do in setting or any extension that needs to be download in vs code to get the hindi characters?
2309:?
2310:?
2311:?
2312:?
2313:?
2314:?
2315:?
2316:?
2317:?
2318:?
2319:?
2320:?
2321:?
2322:?
2323:?
2324:?
2325:?
2326:?
2327:?
2328:?
2329:?
2330:?
2331:?
2332:?
2333:?
2334:?
2335:?
2336:?
2337:?
2338:?
2339:?
2340:?
2341:?
2342:?
2343:?
2344:?
2345:?
2346:?
2347:?
2348:?
2349:?
2350:?
2351:?
2352:?
2353:?
2354:?
2355:?
2356:?
2357:?
2358:?
2359:?
2360:?
2361:?
2362:?


answered here ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950020/display-hindi-language-in-console-using-java

@ticktalk completely different problem.

'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace is what I'm using in VSC. No problem in displaying those characters

tell me the ssteps of changing font

I wish I knew ;)

By the way, I changed first letter of class name to upperclass, per Java conventions. Unrelated to your problem.

@BasilBourque upper case

Hi, you can choose to change the encoding method directly in the bottom right corner. It can also be changed by modifying setting.json file.It's like this
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS": "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
}


@Jeanneli we're talking about fonts now. I think the encoding is set to UTF-8 already

You can use this
as a useful tool to find which fonts support a particular codepoint. Expects hex input, so 0x0905 or \u0905 or U+0905

tl;dr
Change your console’s settings to (a) Use UTF-8, and (b) Use a font containing glyphs for your desired characters.
Your code works

See your code run successfully at Ideone.com.
See your code run successfully at The Java Playground by Oracle. (Paste your two lines of code there.)

2309:अ
2310:आ
2311:इ
2312:ई
2313:उ
2314:ऊ
2315:ऋ
2316:ऌ
2317:ऍ
2318:ऎ
2319:ए
2320:ऐ
2321:ऑ
2322:ऒ
2323:ओ
2324:औ
2325:क
2326:ख
2327:ग
2328:घ
2329:ङ
2330:च
2331:छ
2332:ज
2333:झ
2334:ञ
2335:ट
2336:ठ
2337:ड
2338:ढ
2339:ण
2340:त
2341:थ
2342:द
2343:ध
2344:न
2345:ऩ
2346:प
2347:फ
2348:ब
2349:भ
2350:म
2351:य
2352:र
2353:ऱ
2354:ल
2355:ळ
2356:ऴ
2357:व
2358:श
2359:ष
2360:स
2361:ह
2362:ऺ

By the way, you can collapse your code from two statements to one. And you can use an underscore character to make numeric literals more readable.
for ( int i = 2_309 ; i <= 2_362 ; i++ )
    System.out.println(i + ":" + Character.toString(i));

For fun, here is an entirely different approach to the same effect:
IntStream.rangeClosed( 2_309 , 2_362 ).mapToObj( ( int i ) -> i + ":" + Character.toString( i ) ).forEach( System.out :: println );

By the way, you can soft-code for a particular Unicode-recognized script rather than hard-code the range of code points. See Get the Unicode block or script name for a particular character (code point) in Java.
IntStream
        .rangeClosed( Character.MIN_CODE_POINT , Character.MAX_CODE_POINT )
        .filter( ( int codePoint ) -> Character.UnicodeScript.of( codePoint ) == Character.UnicodeScript.DEVANAGARI )
        .mapToObj( ( int codePoint ) -> codePoint + ":" + Character.toString( codePoint ) )
        .forEach( System.out :: println );

Solution
Change your settings for the console to:

Use UTF-8 character-encoding.
Use a font that includes glyphs for those particular characters.

See:

Change font of output console in Visual Studio?
the manual

Per this Comment,  try these fonts:

'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace


It's a good thing it works for me - I've just searched in vain for 10 minutes to find how to configure the output window ;)

'Droid Sans Mono', 'monospace', monospace
i tried adding this font but getting the same problem. not resolved

import java.util.;
import java.lang.;
import java.io.*;
also i am using this three imports for the first time so any setting need to change ?

@coder Two of your import statements are unused. And java.lang.* is automatically imported by default with no need for your explicit import statement. You can delete all three import lines.  None of these relate to your problem. The console settings are your problem.

still not able to solve the problem.how to add glyphs font invs code ?

Hi, if you want to modify the font. You can use the shortcut key Ctrl+, go to settings, and input editor.font. The font can be customized according to [the document])(https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/appearance#_text-style).
